# how to add data in d3 bubble chart?

Tags: d3.js, push

i want add data in my d3 bubble chart... but i don't know how add to data...

i used some code :

var JData={text:"TEST", count:"100"}
bubbleChart.options.data.items.push(JData[0])
etc....

but i cant added new Circle(bubble)

how to add data in my d3 bubble chart??

```
var bubbleChart = new d3.svg.BubbleChart({
    supportResponsive: true,

    size: 600,

    innerRadius: 600 / 3.5,

    radiusMin: 50,

    data: {           
      items: [
        //not add !!!! not this
        {text: "Php", count: "170"},
        {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
        {text: "D", count: "12"},
        {text: "Python", count: "170"},
        {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
        {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
        {text: "Something", count: "170"},
      ],

      eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
      classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        name: "central-click",
        options: {
          text: "(See more detail)",
          style: {
            "font-size": "12px",
            "font-style": "italic",
            "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
            //"font-weight": "700",
            "text-anchor": "middle",
            "fill": "white"
          },
          attr: {dy: "65px"},
          centralClick: function() {
            alert("Here is more details!!");
          }
        }
      },
      {
        name: "lines",
        options: {
          format: [

            {// Line #0
              textField: "count",
              classed: {count: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "28px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "0px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            },
            {// Line #1
              textField: "text",
              classed: {text: true},
              style: {
                "font-size": "14px",
                "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                "text-anchor": "middle",
                fill: "white"
              },
              attr: {
                dy: "20px",
                x: function (d) {return d.cx;},
                y: function (d) {return d.cy;}
              }
            }
          ],
          centralFormat: [
            {// Line #0
              style: {"font-size": "50px"},
              attr: {}
            },
            {// Line #1
              style: {"font-size": "30px"},
              attr: {dy: "40px"}
            }
          ]
        }
      }]

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything works before you try to add new data, then you probably want to rerun the var bubblechart once you've added data to the array.

my approach would be:

```
var data = {...}//move data outside bubblechart generator
function bubblechart (data) = {
d3.selectAll("svg ").remove()//remove previous graph
... //create bubblechart
...}

var JData={text:"TEST", count:"100"}
data.push(JData[0])
bubblechart(data)
```

This is probably the simplest way, but you could probably add some transitions in to resize the old bubbles rather than adding them all again with the new one.